# Angular update json file helper

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I was wondering if anyone could advise a possible solution to use in my Angular project for the following:

I'm looking to read the json file and ensure that no duplicate values exist so they can be mapped to their relevant classes.
I have 2 main objects which in turn have their own farm objects and each farm object has their own paddock objects. I was wondering what would be the best way to read through the json file and update values that need to match their parent objects e.g. no duplicating paddock id's and each paddock has the correct farm id. As I used json-generator to generate this data each paddock id resets per farm.

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Cole Acosta",
  "address": "Florence Avenue Whipholt",
  "farms": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "aliquip50",
      "name": "Remotion",
      "harvestedDateTime": "2018-06-20",
      "farmType": "Cane",
      "millerId": 1,
      "paddocks": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "code": "elit171",
          "area": 697,
          "farmId": 1
        },

export class Miller {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    farms: Farm[];
}

export class Farm extends Miller {
    id: number;
    code: string;
    name: string;
    harvestedDateTime: Date;
    farmType: 'Cane' | 'Rice' | 'Other';
    millerId: number;
    paddocks: Paddock[];
}

export class Paddock extends Farm {
    id: number;
    code: string;
    area: number;
    farmId: number;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear with the question?

Comment: I'm looking to ensure that according to the above snippet of json, that each farm id is correctly represented in their appropriate paddock and each paddock id is not duplicated.

Comment: question is still unclear. Please edit. Probably an example would help.